# plt.text() aligning with categorical variable rather than numeric

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I think this should be fairly straight forward but I'm having trouble with it.. how can I center a label over a category rather than over an absolute position.

EX: I want the median label to be centered over the "Lower" category.
[image]

How can I modify the code below to center this text above "Lower"??

```
## plot strip plot
ax = sns.stripplot(x="Metric", y="Percent Error", data=dat,
                   jitter=0.3,
                   alpha = 0.5,
                   color = '#a54f7e',
                   linewidth=1,
                   edgecolor = '#a54f7e')

## Set title and axis
plt.title('Error Metrics')
ax.set(yscale="log")

## get median
lower_med = round(df['percent_error_lower'].median(),2)

## add text label 
plt.text(0, lower_med,'{:.2f} \n (Median)'.format(lower_med))
```

Comment: Do you mean above the label "Lower" or above the plotted points at the top?

Comment: y = the value of lower_med and x would equal "lower" or appear to be centered over lower.

Comment: Are you trying to label the location of the median? Why not use an overlayed box plot?

Comment: Even if I do a box plot I still want to label the median with text, so the problem still stands.

Comment: What would be the problem with `ax.text(0, lower_med, f'{lower_med:.2f} \n (Median)', ha='center', va='center')`?

Comment: @JohanC this worked! Thank you!